# Fisher information in logit model

Tags: regression, logistic, mathematical-statistics, fisher-information

I'm working at Score test realization and I need to calculate the Fisher information in basic logistic model,
$$\text{Logit}(\Pr(Y_i=1))=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i$$

And I have stuck at the calculation of this expectation: $$I=E\big(\sum_iX_i^2f(\beta_0+\beta_1X_i)(1-f(\beta_0+\beta_1X_i)\big)$$ such that $ f=\frac1{1+e^{-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i} }$.

Maybe someone has already faced this same problem?

Calculations:

Hypothesis: $$H_0: \beta_s=0 \text{vs. } H_1: \beta_s\neq0$$
Likelihood function: $l=\Pi_{i=1}^{n} (f_i)$

Statistics:
\begin{align}
U(\beta_s)&=\frac{\partial\big(\ln L(\beta_s)\big)}{\partial\beta_s}\\
V(\beta_s)&=-E\bigg( \frac{\partial^2\big(\ln L(\beta_s)\big)}{\partial\beta_s^2}\bigg)
\end{align}

Calculating U statistic:
\begin{align}
L(Y_i,\beta_s)&=\ln(l(Y_i,\beta_s))\\
&=\ln\big( \Pi_i f_i(Y_i,\beta_s)\big)\\
&=\sum_i \ln f_i(Y)={\sum_i \bigg( \ln\left(Pr(Y=1)\big)^{Y_i}  \big(Pr(Y=0)\right)^{(1-Y_i)} \bigg)} \\
&=\sum_i \left( Y_i\ln\big(Pr(Y_i=1)\big) + (1-Y_i)\ln\left(1-Pr(Y_i=1)\right) \right) \\
 &=\sum_i \left( Y_i\ln\left(f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})\right) + (1-Y_i)\ln\left(1-f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})\right) \right)\\ 
 &= \sum_i \bigg((\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})(Y_i-1)+\ln(\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})}} \bigg)\\
 &= \sum_i \bigg((\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})(Y_i-1)-\ln(1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}  \bigg)
\end{align}

Taking the derivative by $\beta_s$:
${ \sum_i \bigg(X_{s,i}\big(Y_i - f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})\big) \bigg)}$

At least: $V$ statistic is the expectation of the derivative of $U$ by $\beta_s$,
\begin{align}
U(\beta_s)'_{\beta_s}&=\bigg( \sum_i X_{s,i}\big(Y_i - f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i})\big) \bigg)'_{\beta_s}\\
&=\sum_i \bigg( X_{s,i}\big(Y_i - \frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}}\big)'_{\beta_s} \bigg)\\
&=\sum_i \bigg( X_{s,i}(-1)(-1)\frac{-X_{s,i}e^{-\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i}}}{\big( 1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}\big) ^2} \bigg)\\
&=\sum_i -X_{s,i}^2\bigg(\frac{e^{-\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i}}}{\big( 1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}\big) ^2} \bigg)
\end{align}

For every $\xi$,
$$\frac{\xi}{(1+\xi)^2}=\frac{1}{1+\xi}\big( 1- \frac{1}{1+\xi} \big)$$

and thus
\begin{align}
U(\beta_s)'_{\beta_s}&=-\sum_i X_{s,i}^2\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}}\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-(\beta_0-\beta_sX_{s,i})}} \right)  \\
&=-\sum_i X_{s,i}^2 f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i}) \big( 1-f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i}) \big) 
\end{align}

Now I should take expectation of this and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the log likelihood?

Comment: If the information is as you claim, then you can eliminate the expectation, because (in a traditional regression setting) it is taken over $Y|X$, and $Y$ is not present. But, I echo @frage_man's concern about earlier errors; could you add a summary of your work to this point?

Comment: I added calculations.

Comment: So I think your derivations are correct. So the Fisher info is evaluated at the MLE from the FOC, which here doesn't have a closed form solution. So I'm not sure what you expect to get.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I don't know what FOC is. I found the realization, where Fisher info is evaluated as $\sum_i \bigg((X_{s,i}^2- \bar X)\bar Y \big( 1-\bar Y) \big) \bigg)$ (Where $ \bar Y$ is an estimate for $f(\beta_0+X \beta_1)$). I wanted to receive the same result and current result is close to expected.

Comment: Oops, I meant $\sum_i \bigg((X_{s,i}- \bar X)^2 \bar Y \big( 1-\bar Y) \big) \bigg)$

Comment: Thank you very much. I found an error in calculations: Fisher info is calculated as $-E\bigg( \frac{\partial^2\big(lnL(\beta_s)\big)}{\partial\beta_s^2}\bigg) $ only in regular models. So we need this condition: $E\big(U(\beta_s)\big)=0$ that is equivalent to $EX=0$. Finally, that means X must be centered and this $\sum_i \bigg((X_{}- \bar X)^2 \bar Y \big( 1-\bar Y) \big) \bigg) $ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calculations was correct. I forgot that Fisher info formula is $-E\bigg( \frac{\partial^2\big(lnL(\beta_s)\big)}{\partial\beta_s^2}\bigg)$ only in regular models. So to get the right answer we must center $X$, and then, as @eric_kernfeld told, eliminate expectation.

The correct result is $\sum_i \bigg((X_{s,i}-\bar X)^2 f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i}) \big( 1-f(\beta_0+\beta_sX_{s,i}) \big) \bigg)$